# Android onResume and onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a question regarding the logic of the life cycle of activities:

[image]

When I learned Android, setting up an Activity was always done in the `onCreate()` function. Now when I resume my Activity, there might be stuff to be done in the `onResume()` that has already been done in `onCreate()`. But then, why would we not just put all the stuff into `onResume()`?

Comment: onCreate is called when activity is created and you initialize your views there once. onResume is called when activity is resumed say from a paused state like a dialog been displayed and your activity is paused. So you don't want to initialize views again in onResume

Comment: Just to clarify on @Raghunandan point, `onResume()` *is also called* when the `Activity` first opens. So, if you need code to run when it first opens **and** when it comes to the foreground from being paused, put that code in `onResume()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why would we not just put all the stuff into onResume()?

Well `onCreate()` is called when your `Activity` is created and you need to initialize some very important things of your application like your main layout!.

Comment: Good point! I like the way codeMagic explained it in his comment too, that onResume is helpful for things that run when the app opens *and* when it returns to the foreground.

Comment: This is really a great answer. Seems so obvious, but now I better understand this workflow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because some staff you don't want to do all the time activity resumed (like findViewById), It can be done once.
Activity can be resumed many times (with dialogs, for example). Do not waste resources.

Answer (score 0):

OnCreate Method start when you open the activty for first time or open activity after kill app so you should locate all stuffs you need to initialize for once like setContentView or some variables.
For example when you run your app with IDE , on create method will call
But if after creating activity press home button activity will pause
And then open the app with recent app to call onresume() method
For better realize initialize all activity method with Log.i(tag,text)